# Daily historical mean thresholding

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
         USER   MEDIA DD_MM          SCORES
0         4       mw  02/11          9737662
1         4       dk  03/11         11691966
2         4       ma  02/11          5140069
3         4       mw  03/11         10165111
4         4       mw  01/11          8962654
5         4       dk  02/11         10112785
6         4       ma  03/11          5661891
7         4       ma  01/11          4942428
8         4       dk  01/11         12246323
0         5       ma  03/11           314034
1         5       mw  01/11         16071400
2         5       dk  03/11         16767571
3         5       dk  01/11         20256912
4         5       dk  02/11         15766468
5         5       mw  02/11         18605524
6         5       mw  03/11         20559416
7         5       ma  02/11           260323
8         5       ma  01/11           287743
0         8       mw  03/11          2155365
1         8       dk  01/11          1787907
2         8       ma  03/11          1516463
3         8       dk  02/11           592109
4         8       mw  01/11          1874539
5         8       mw  02/11           801637
6         8       ma  01/11          1187740
```

The goal is to try to predict whether new information that comes in is not anomalous data.
How can I set a threshold using this as historical data? For instance when new data comes in, that has this attributes: `user =4, media = dk, scores = 500`, this should be classified as an anomaly. Upon further research, I realized I had to find the historical daily mean and then take two standard deviations away from the mean. How do I calculate that?

Comment: Based on what algorithm do you classify rows?

Comment: If you don't have an algorithm, you can develop a model with Tensorflow.

Comment: I query the data from a large database. I want to stick to statistical significance. It is less complicated for what I want to do :)

Comment: Sorry mate I don't exactly see how you wanna do it but added a possible example way :)

Comment: No probs. I will take a look at ur example. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5],'B':[9,8,7,6,5],'C':[2,5,7,9,11]})
```

Let's say you want to classify its rows into some categories using this function:

```
def rowclassifier(row):
    if sum(row)>15:
        return 'much'
    else:
        return 'not much'
```

Then you can do:

```
df['class']=df[['A','B','C']].apply(lambda row: rowclassifier(row),axis=1)
```

`df` will be:

```
    A   B   C   class
0   1   9   2   not much
1   2   8   5   not much
2   3   7   7   much
3   4   6   9   much
4   5   5   11  much
```

---

If you have a `rowclassifier` function for your own data, I think you can apply the method above.